# How to overflow a column inside a modal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have spent a few hours trying to get this to work. I have a (full screen) modal, and it flexes its body to grow according to the modal. Inside this body, I have container, a row, and 2 columns. Since the modal-body doesn't have a height set, I am unable to limit the height (max-height, maybe) of the column to make it overflow.

How do I properly achieve the expected behavior in this scenario? I want the modal body to respect the screen's height, but activating column's overflow.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3t5p6xq

```
<div class="modal" id="fullModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Full Screen Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div style="width: 80%; display: inline-block;">asd</div>
        <div
            class="overflow-auto"
            style="width: 20%; display: inline-block"
        >
            Right Column
            <p>
            new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
            line<br />
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">
            Save
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button
    id="fullModalButton"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#fullModal"
>
    Click me
</button>
```

CSS

```
p {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.modal-dialog {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.modal-body {
  /* modal-body dimensions are automatically calculated, since it uses flex */
  /* the body expands, while header and footer have fixed height */
}

.container-fluid {
  /* since modal-body doesn't have a height set, I can't set max-height in this element */
}

.row {
  /* since container-fluid doesn't have a height set, I can't set max-height in this element */
}

.col-4 {
  overflow: auto;
  /* since row doesn't have a height set, I can't set max-height in this element */
  /* this causes this column to overflow */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding `.overflow-auto` to all parent divs (starting at `.modal-content`) and specifying `.h-100` on `.container-fluid`, `.row` and `.col-4` 
Chrome DevTools are of great help for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `bootstrap`, I'm not sure why you would add some custom CSS that is already built-in with bootstrap. Here is what I would do. I set the column's height limit to 300px as an example or you can set it based on the screen size using `@media` or `percentage` and set the overflow to its element:

```css
.h-300 {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
          <div class="col-8">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 h-300 overflow-auto">
            <p>
              new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
              line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new line<br />new
              line<br />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't use bootstrap classes to help me try different combinations of styles. Thank you for your help.